# Initializing Cassandra schema

Tags: automation, devops, cassandra, kubernetes

Recently I have started working on a project in which we are using Cassandra. It's a quite a new project, so we haven't decided how to initialize the schema.
We are using Docker and Kubernetes. I've read many articles stating a good solution is to load required scripts to Docker container to entrypoint.d (if there is one).
Another solution would be to use initContainer/Helm Hook to load a configMap with the schema script.
The next one is to create a bash script to run it manually. The last one seems the worst solution, at least for me.

How is schema initialization done in real world projects?